# How do I fix this Roll20 macro for starting gold after first level?

Tags: dnd-5e, roll20

Can anyone help with this macro? I am trying to generate random starting gold per PC levels, but it only allows me to do it if I put a character’s name. For example:

```
[[@{Javi "Bones" Rorrey|base_level} *100 +1d10 *25]]
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to do it for all your players? Kinda like a **for every player do**?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do? How do you expect it to calculate the result without specifying a character to use the level of? (Also, note that `base_level` will calculate based on only their starting class, which is different from character level if the character is multiclassed.)

Comment: @Chepelink Yes I do, or mostly so when they generate a PC, they can generate it themselves.

Comment: @FranciscoDeLaPaz - Might need the API? Doesn't look like looping is really native to the macro language - https://app.roll20.net/forum/post/653944/slug%7D

Comment: @JohnP Thank you for the link. The answer was just to make a query for input.   
                                                                                                                                 
           You get [[100 *?{level} +1d10 *25]] starting gold

Comment: @FranciscoDeLaPaz - Glad it helped, even if I was looking at the wrong part of the problem. :) I thought you wanted to loop and do it multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

The answer was just to make a query for input. You get `[[100 *?{level} +1d10 *25]]` starting gold. Thank you @JohnP for pointing me in right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Another way for the players to do this is to use `[[@{selected|base_level} *100 +1d10 *25]]`

This allows a player or GM to select the token and roll for the gold. This works best when set-up in the macros bar or/and as a token action. There is an option to show it to -target- at the bottom of the "Edit Macros" windows, it can be shown to a specific player or to all players (or just the GM).